# Justify the limit is infinite

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I justify that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} = \infty$$

correctly? I think I need to calculate the left and right hand limits, but is that trully necessary or should I do this in a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since you have $x^2$ in there, this is always $+$ve for $x \in \Bbb R $

Comment: I know, but I want to justify it severely

Answer (score 1):

Let $M > 0$ , choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon < \dfrac{1}{M\cdot \sqrt{M}}$, Then if $|x| < \epsilon$, $\dfrac{1}{|x|} > M\cdot \sqrt{M}$, and $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} > \left(M\cdot \sqrt{M}\right)^{2/3} = M$ which proves the limit to be $+\infty$

Alternately, put $y^3 = x^2$, then $x \to 0 \iff x^2 \to 0^+ \iff y^3 \to 0^+ \iff y \to 0^+$. So: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} = \displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0^+} \dfrac{1}{y} = +\infty$

Comment: Not using the definition, I just want to know if calculate the left and right hand limits is a correct way!

Comment: There are definitions for left and right hand limits, @Giiovanna, hehe. I think the only way to justify it is really to use such definitions and that anything else is imprecise. You could try noting that As x-> 0, 1/x^odd -> plus and minus \infty, but as x->0, 1/x^even is plus \infty. In your question, we can make a substitution by letting y=x^(1/3) where y->0 as x->0, but then again how do we show that as x->0, 1/x^even is plus \infty? Definition right?